# How to find which AWS account a loadbalancer is pointed to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

A really lame question, but I can't seem to google it, sorry. I have the LoadBalancer URL and have quite a few AWS accounts that it might be under.

How does one figure out reliably which account the LoadBalancer and respective VMs are under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave the question in case someone else Googles this. Basically for security reasons it's not possible to find out which account a LoadBalancer points to. You need to go through your deployments and figure it out.

Comment: Please don't leave the question open - please accept your own answer if you're confident it's correct.

Comment: @Tim Yup - will do as soon as the 48 hour wait period for accepting an own answer expires :)